# Is UV light necessary for vitamin D generation?

Tags: dermatology, micronutrients

As far as I know, glass blocks [UV light, which is cancerous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_light_and_cancer).

Do we generate vitamin D behind a glass window, if we sit in the sun?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: [No.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960076005002220)

Longer answer: [UVB rays are essential for Vitamin D synthesis](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25754279). According to some studies, [1 hour of sunshine](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23441390) is needed even in sunny climates - but only in average, still depending on latitude, skin color and other factors - to prevent Vitamin D deficiency. Still, even the average sun exposure in mid-latitude regions summers [might not fulfill your body's needs for UV radation](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25754279) to supply itself with Vitamin D, but opinions on this differ (as can be seen in comparison with the first link of this paragraph).

But when comparing it to 1 hour of full sun exposure in mild climates, it is safe to conclude that the UVB levels behind glass windows, as measured in the first overall link above, are so low that it is highly improbable to reach sufficient Vitamin D levels behind them.